# Target a div only when another div in the dom has a class of X

Tags: css

Is there a way to target `div.music` only when the div a few more up has a class of `success`? The `success` class gets added dynamically so I only want to target `div.music` when `.success` exists in the DOM.

For example, I know that if `.music` was right below `.success`, I can do something like this:

`.success + .music { styles here }` using the adjacent selector. However, what if the two divs aren't adjacent to each other like this?

```
<div>
    <div class="success"></div>
    <div class="blah"></div>
    <div class="blah"></div>
    <div class="blah"></div>
    <div class="music"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors): `~`

```
.success ~ .music {
   color:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/d9rh2cyt/)**

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

Comment: Awesome, looks like it has good support too. Thank you, I'll accept your answer in ETA 9 min.